# Is it possible to exclude some fields from assertJ usingFieldByFieldElementComparator?

Tags: java, assertions, assertj

How to achieve the below:

```
List<Data> streams = new ArrayList<>();
assertThat(streams).usingFieldByFieldElementComparatorIgnoringGivenFields("createdOn").containsOnly(data1, data2);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`ListAssert.usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields(String... fields)`](http://javadox.com/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.4.1/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields-java.lang.String...-) that does the same thing as [`ListAssert.usingFieldByFieldElementComparator()`](http://javadox.com/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.4.1/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#usingFieldByFieldElementComparator--) but by allowing to ignore some fields/properties :

> Use field/property by field/property comparison on all
>   fields/properties except the given ones

So you could write :

```
List<Data> streams = new ArrayList<>();
//...
Assertions.assertThat(streams)
          .usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields("createdOn")
          .containsOnly(data1, data2);
```

Comment: Is it possible to relax comparison of Date() by 1000ms (isCloseTo operation) in the above code format you have suggested ?

Comment: @Vel Ganesh You are welcome. I don't think that it be possible with this AssertJ comparator. For such requirements, I generally exclude it from the AssertJ comparison and I  perform it with a JUnit assertion  such as: `Assert.assertTrue(date.after(lowerLimitDate) && date.before(upperLimitDate));`

Comment: I had trouble with it for whatever odd reason, but using `usingElementComparatorOnFields("foo", "bar")` was quite useful.

Comment: `usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields` is deprecated, now you should use `usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparatorIgnoringFields` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you (1) have control of the source code of `data` and (2) are using [Lombok annotations](https://projectlombok.org/) then you can use the `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` against the `createdOn` field e.g.

```java
import lombok.*;

@Data
public class Data {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude   // will not include this field in the generated equals and hashCode methods.
    private Date createdOn;

    ...
}
```

This really simplifies the testing:

```java
assertThat(streams).containsOnly(data1, data2);
```

> **NOTE:** if you do use `equals()` methods on the `Data` object as part of the `src/main/java` classes, you will need to ensure the values of the other fields are enough to make the object unique so that `equals()` works properly when using `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`.